# Remote access to IIS 5.1 via NTLM

Tags: iis, authentication, remote-access, ntlm

I'm trying to configure remote access to IIS 5.1 web server on a virtual xp machine. The web server is used to expose a ASP.NET web service. 
I want to access the web service using Java client by using NTLM authentication.

So I'm making a prototype using virtual machine and web browser. All firewalls are off. I have IIS set up to only authenticate users by integrated authorization (no guest, basic, digest access). On guest browser logging in just works.

However, when I try to access the site from the host computer (windows 7) using web browser (ie, ff, chrome) I always get 401.1 - not authorized error.

I have looked for reason of such behaviour and have applied two Ms fixes which seem to be related:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871179 (cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM")
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957097 (DisableLoopbackCheck -> 1)

I'm starting to wonder if I'm not doing something stupid here. The guest computer name is virtual and username user. In host browser login prompts I enter "virtual\user" and password of "password".

I am a Linux user, so maybe I'm missing something obvious for Windows admins?

Comment: Those loopback settings are not useful if you're connecting from a different computer (host->Guest counts as a different computer, or virtual machines wouldn't be worth much.) If you can log on as that user locally, you should be able to do NTLM to the machine.